# How do I take the end of a message on discord and make my bot repeat it?

Tags: python, discord

How do I have my bot take the end of a message and repeat it with a message behind it? Here's my code:

```
elif message.content.startswith('/ban'):
        bant = message.content.endswith('') and ('has been bant')
        await client.send_message(message.channel, bant)
```

If I say for example /ban chiken

I want it to say: chiken has been bant

Or if I say /ban jeff

I want it to say: jeff has been bant

Answer (score 0):

`message.content` is a string like `"/ban jeff"`

We can use `str.split` to split the message on the first space

```
_, target = message.content.split(' ', 1)
```

`target` will be `"jeff"`

For longer strings, `/ban jeff andy`,  we are only spliting once, so `target` will be `"jeff andy"`.

We can then use this to build our response

```
bant = '{} has been bant'.format(target)
```

Answer (score 0):

`discord.Message.content` returns a string, so you would need to do simple string manipulation. Luckily python is a very nice language to do this in.

```
# There are various ways to address the issue.
# These are ranked from most recommended to least

# assuming content is: '/ban daisy boo foo'

arguments = message.content.lstrip('/ban')
# returns 'daisy boo foo'

arguments = message.content.split(' ', 1)
# returns 'daisy boo foo'

arguments = shlex.split(message.content)[1:]
# returns ['/ban', 'daisy', 'boo', 'foo']
# but we slice it to just ['daisy', 'boo', 'foo']

arguments = message.content[len('/ban'):]
# returns 'daisy boo foo'
```

If you're considering using this if/elif content startswith certain pattern methodology to suppliment a commands feature to your bot I wouldn't reccomend it, discord.py comes packed with its own commands extentsion to suit these issues directly.

As a basic example of how to use the commands extension to do this, here is some code.

(Assuming discord.py [rewrite 1.0.0a](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/))

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/')

@bot.command()
async def ban(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    await user.ban()

@ban.error
async def ban_error(ctx, error):
    await ctx.send(error)

bot.run('token')
```